Polygon with circular arcs instead of edges?
Is there a name for a polygon-like figure defined by points in the plane, some of which are connected by circular arcs of given radii?
Here would be two based on the pentagram:


I just grabbed these images from the net. I'm not sure their edges are circular!

Hypocycloid is somewhat related to this. You can start your search from there. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid
